# Show interstitialAd after 30 seconds Audience Network Facebook

Tags: android-studio, handler, android-handler, interstitial, facebook-audience-network

I want to use Facebook Audience Network for my Android app, I have integrated interstitialAd in-app and it works fine but it appears as Activity launch. I want to show ad after 30 seconds. this is my code

```
 interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, "1555910157949688_1556058954601475");

    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
      

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            // Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed
            Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed!");
            // Show the ad
            interstitialAd.show();
        }

       
    });

    interstitialAd.loadAd();
```

and I have tried this to schedule my ad but it did not work.

```
private void showAdWithDelay() {
   Handler handler = new Handler();
   handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
            // Check if interstitialAd has been loaded successfully
           if(interstitialAd == null || !interstitialAd.isAdLoaded()) {
               return;
           }
            // Check if the ad is already expired or invalidated, and do not show ad if that is the case. You will not get paid to show an invalidated ad.
           if(interstitialAd.isAdInvalidated()) {
               return;
           }
           // Show the ad
            interstitialAd.show(); 
       }
   }, 3000); 
}
```

Comment: you used 3000 which is 3 secs pls use 30 * 1000 for 30 secs

Comment: yes i am using 30000 it was mistake in question

Comment: I suggest you to instantiate the interstitialAd object b/w 25 secs or 30 secs coz sometimes it depends on network and the ad will show with a delay of 3-4 secs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to do this:

```
      Handler handler = new Handler();
      interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, "XXX");
      interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
          handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              interstitialAd.show();
            }
          }, YOUR_TIME);
        }
      });

      interstitialAd.loadAd();
```

And if you want to be more precise, do it:

```
      final long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      Handler handler = new Handler();
      interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, "XXX");
      interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
          long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
          long timeWait;
          if (now - lastTime >= YOUR_TIME){
            timeWait = 0;
          }else {
            timeWait = YOUR_TIME-(now-lastTime);
          }
          handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              interstitialAd.show();
            }
          }, timeWait);
        }
      });

      interstitialAd.loadAd();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your implementation is breaking AdMob policies and could get you some trouble.

Check this page for help on right/wrong Interstitial implementations (Specially the "Interstitials that unexpectedly launch" point): https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2936214

To comply with AdMob policies I suggest you only show Interstitials in activity/app natural transitions, different implementations could lead you to get banned from Admob.

To do so, you could change your code to first just load the Ad and keep track of its loaded status like this:

```
boolean isAdLoaded = false;

interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, "1555910157949688_1556058954601475");

interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() 
{ 
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) 
    {
        // Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed
        Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad is loaded and ready to be displayed!");
        // The ad has been loaded
        isAdLoaded = true;
    }
});

interstitialAd.loadAd();
```

And then show it in a natural transition of the app, for example when the user taps a button to go to a different activity:

```
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //Show interstitial if it is loaded
        if(isAdLoaded)
            interstitialAd.show();
        
        //Open Activity
        startActivity(new Intent(this,OtherActivity.class));
    }
});
```